# Show ViewController programmatically (not working)

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

I got a main VC called "ViewController.swift", which is bond to my ViewController Scene in Main.storyboard. 
Then I want another screen, which shows when a condition in my ViewController.swift is fulfilled. 
Therefore I got a Gameover.storyboard, which has a VC Scene with Storyboard ID "overID" as well as a "GameoverViewController.swift" to handle the GameOver Scene.

Here is my code in ViewController.swift, which should open Gameover.storyboards VC Scene when the condition you see below is fulfilled:

```
       import UIKit

        class ViewController: UIViewController {
            var wantedLiter = 10.00
            var timer : Timer?
            var actualLiter = 0.00
            var timerReset = true
            var preisProLiter = 1.26


//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


            let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Gameover", bundle: nil)

            let gameoverViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "overID") as! GameoverViewController 

//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

            @IBOutlet weak var preisliterLabel: UILabel!
            @IBOutlet weak var euroLabel: UILabel!
            @IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!
            @IBOutlet weak var numberButton: UIButton!
            @IBOutlet weak var confirmButton: UIButton!


            @IBAction func confirm(_ sender: Any) {

            }

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                numberLabel.text = String(round(1000*actualLiter)/1000) //initial value
                preisliterLabel.text = String(preisProLiter)
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            }

            @IBAction func holdingTheButton(_ sender: Any) {
                print("I am holding")
                       timerReset = false // reset to false since you are holding the button
                       guard timer == nil else { return }
                       timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.005, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            }


            @IBAction func buttonReleased(_ sender: Any) {
                print("button released")
                if (wantedLiter == actualLiter){
                    print("WIN!")
                    actualLiter = 0;
                }
               //startTime = 0.00
                 timer?.invalidate()
                 timer = nil
               // timerReset = true // reset to true since you released.
            }


            @objc func updateTime(){
                //update label every second

                print("updating label ")
                if (wantedLiter <= actualLiter){
                    print("Ooops")
                    actualLiter = 0; 

//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


self.present(gameoverViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) 

//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

                }

               actualLiter += 0.01
               numberLabel.text = String(round(1000*actualLiter)/1000)
               euroLabel.text = String((round(100*actualLiter*preisProLiter)/100))

            }
        }
```

And now got you some Screenshots, which might help.

[image: Overview]

[image: Main ViewController Scene]

[image: Gameover SCENE (can't choose GameoverViewController as Class here)]

If you need more Screens, please ask.

Right now, I got following errors:

1) ViewController.swift in the upper part marked with "!!!!..."

Cannot use instance member 'storyBoard' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

2) ViewController.swift

Cannot convert value of type 'gameoverViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

3) ViewController.swift upper Part:

Use of undeclared type 'GameoverViewController'

[image: Source of GameoverViewController I hope..]

This is how I changed the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var wantedLiter = 10.00
    var timer : Timer?
    var actualLiter = 0.00
    var timerReset = true
    var preisProLiter = 1.26


   let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Gameover", bundle: nil)
    var gameoverViewController: GameoverViewController!

    @IBOutlet weak var preisliterLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var euroLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var confirmButton: UIButton!


    @IBAction func confirm(_ sender: Any) {

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gameoverViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "overID") as? GameoverViewController

        numberLabel.text = String(round(1000*actualLiter)/1000) //initial value
        preisliterLabel.text = String(preisProLiter)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func holdingTheButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print("I am holding")
               timerReset = false // reset to false since you are holding the button
               guard timer == nil else { return }
               timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.005, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


    @IBAction func buttonReleased(_ sender: Any) {
        print("button released")
        if (wantedLiter == actualLiter){
            print("WIN!")
            actualLiter = 0;
        }
       //startTime = 0.00
         timer?.invalidate()
         timer = nil
       // timerReset = true // reset to true since you released.
    }


    @objc func updateTime(){
        //update label every second

        print("updating label ")
        if (wantedLiter <= actualLiter){
            print("Ooops")
            actualLiter = 0;
            self.present(gameoverViewController as! UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

       actualLiter += 0.01
       numberLabel.text = String(round(1000*actualLiter)/1000)
       euroLabel.text = String((round(100*actualLiter*preisProLiter)/100))

    }
}
```

(not working)

And I changed the GameoverViewController type to UIViewController.

But where was my Typo?? (G instead of g)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the initializer for `gameoverViewController` into `viewDidLoad` or the like and make `gameoverViewController` an optional or implicitly unwrapped optional (that's the `!` after a type)
2. Should be fixed by 1.
3. Please show the source for GameoverViewController if this is not fixed by 1. too.

Comment: I moved "let gameoverViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(with identifier: "overID") as! GameoverViewController " into viewDidLoad, but unfortunately the compiler says for this line "Use of undeclared type 'GameoverViewController'"..  where exactly do you want me to add a "!" ?

Comment: @RacketCoder If you move the *declaration* of this variable into the initializer, you cannot access it in `updateTime` later. You'll have to retain it as a property but *initialize* it in `viewDidLoad`. Read up on these terms if you don't know them. As I said, please show the source for GameoverViewController then.

Comment: I added the shource for GameoverViewController (I hope). And there is no code yet, except import UIKit

class gameoverViewController: NSObject {
}

Comment: @RacketCoder Casing matters in Swift. Lower case vs uppercase G. That aside, you’ll not be able to use a subclass of NSObject as a view controller, i.e. use it with `present`. View controllers must be a subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: I added my changes to the main question

Comment: @RacketCoder Do you need to use a storyboard for GameOverViewController? Or a .xib file will be okay.

Comment: .xib file will be okay